# i want to know how to set my stop loss according to lowest of 5 bars from my entry candle in pine script trading view

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

this is the code i used

```
var float long_stop = 0
if buy
   long_stop := ta.lowest(low, 5)
plot(long_stop)
```

but i am not getting the desired outpit

[image]

the candle with an green arrow below is my entry candle and i want my stop loss to be set at the blue horizontal line as it the lowest of the 5 candle before my entry candle. how should i code that?

Answer (score 0):

Do not ignore warning messages. This code should give you a warning message as you are calling `ta.lowest()` in a local scope.

Call it in the global scope instead and assign the result to your `long_stop` variable when your `buy` condition is `true`.

```
var float long_stop = 0

lowest_ = ta.lowest(low, 5)

if buy
    long_stop := lowest_
plot(long_stop)
```

Comment: i didnt know what the error message meant. your code worked. thank you